# Blank screen with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and using some tutorials but i only get black screen while on the videos developpers get their widget on the screen. i've tried multiple solutions but i dont really understand what the problem is. I am trying to build a login screen here is the code i wrote :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 

class LoginScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen,self).__int__(**kwargs)
        sm=ScreenManager
        Screen=Screen(name="screen")
        layout=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.Username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.Password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="username"))
        layout.add_widget(self.Username)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="password"))
        layout.add_widget(self.Password)
        Screen.add_widget(layout)
        sm.add_widget(Screen)
        return sm   

class simplekivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    simplekivy().run()
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: correct your indentation, in python it is important

Comment: it is correct in the python file i just missed it here i'm correcting it right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- The constructor method is called `__init__`, it is not called `__int__`.
- The constructor method should not return anything
- The variables should not be called the same as the classes or functions, I mean the following code: `Screen=Screen(name="screen")`.
- It is best to segment is to separate your code, with the name of the class LoginScreen I think you want to make a Screen, so create another class that is the ScreenManager.
- Another error is that you have not imported Label.

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.Username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.Password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="username"))
        layout.add_widget(self.Username)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="password"))
        layout.add_widget(self.Password)
        self.add_widget(layout) 

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManager,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_widget(LoginScreen())

class simplekivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    simplekivy().run()
```

Comment: Oooh my god now i understand... thank you very much for your help

Comment: @naxcuo If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: [tour] :P